# Firebase push notification delay after triggering few high priority notifications

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use Firebase high priority push notifications to trigger Panic alarms in Android devices. For first few tries of push, immediately push notifications arrives and it works great. But when i keep triggering push notifications after certain amount of time slowly delay keeps increasing.

I want it to trigger immediately as it is Panic situation.

I also followed [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message) which read:

> **High priority**: FCM attempts to deliver high priority messages immediately, allowing the FCM service to wake a sleeping device when necessary and to run some limited processing (including very limited network access). High priority messages generally should result in user interaction with your app or its notifications. If FCM detects a pattern in which they don't, your messages may be de-prioritized. Android P introduced app standby buckets which limit the number of FCM high priority messages you can send to your app that don't result in the user using your app or viewing a notification. If, in response to a high priority message, a notification is displayed in a way that is visible to the user, then your app standby bucket quota will not be consumed by that message.
>
> Because a small portion of the Android mobile population are on high latency networks, avoid opening a connection to your servers before displaying a notification. Calling back to the server before the end of the allowed processing time may be risky for users on high latency networks. Instead, include the notification content in the FCM message and display it immediately. If you need to sync for additional in-app content on Android, you can schedule an FJD job or a JobIntentService to handle that in the background.

How can I make sure high priority messages are triggered as soon as possible? May be within a minute in all cases.

Comment: I believe there's a limit on how many high priority notifications you can send through FCM. **EDIT:** The description you posted perfectly explains why you might not receive notifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FCM attempts to deliver high priority messages immediately, allowing the FCM service to wake a sleeping device when necessary and to run some limited processing (including very limited network access). High priority messages generally should result in user interaction with your app or its notifications. If FCM detects a pattern (such as testing pattern) then your messages may be de-prioritized. Android P introduced app standby buckets which limit the number of FCM high priority messages you can send to your app that don't result in the user using your app or viewing a notification. If, in response to a high priority message, a notification is displayed in a way that is visible to the user, then your app standby bucket quota will not be consumed by that message.

Comment: Include reference to official docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#setting-the-priority-of-a-message

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/power/power-details

Comment: So how Instant Message App like WhatsApp deal with it, as every message sent from for friends seems high priority (you don't want to miss a message from your girl friends, I guess)